# Sending Ether between two contracts not working

Tags: solidity-0.6.x

I am trying to transfer some Ether between two contracts but it is just not working for me. Here is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract ContractA {
    uint public tips;

    /**
     * Function to collect the tips.
     */
    function collectTips(address payable _recipient) public {
        require(_recipient.send(tips));
        tips = 0;
    }
    
    /**
     * Receive function in order to receive tips. No calldata is set
     */
    receive () external payable {
        tips += msg.value;
    } 
}

contract ContractB {
    uint256 public tips;
    
    /**
     * Receive function in order to receive tips. No calldata is set
     */
    receive() external payable {
        tips += msg.value;
    }
}
```

Whenever I send a transaction to `collectTips`, giving the contract address of `ContractB` I get the following error in remix

```
transact to ContractA.collectTips errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

I was referring to these docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.0/contracts.html#receive-ether-function

I am clueless. Anyone an idea what I am doing wrong?

I found also sort of the same question around here, but nothing helped. Either the Solidity version is too old or just not working for me :/

Best and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending Ether using `send` or `transfer` only forwards `23000` gas of which `21000` is consumed by the context switching and the remaining `2000` is not enough to write to `storage` as `tips` is being updated in the `receive` function of `contractB`. The reads/writes to `storage` which will require around 5500 gas plus the 21000 gas for context switching.

```
function collectTips(address payable _recipient) public {
        (bool success, ) = _recipient.call{value: tips, gas: 5500}("");
        require(success);
        tips = 0;
}
```

The above implementation will explicitly send `21000 + 5500` gas along with the Ether sending transaction and the transaction will not revert.

Comment: Have you tried your solution in remix? I had to change gas to `19000` in order to make it work. Did it work for you with the `5500` gas? Which Solidity version did you use? I am using `0.6.0`

Comment: yes, the first time it will cost 20000 gas to store a value into storage of contractB and if you send the second time it costs 5000 gas to update the storage in conbtractB hence the change.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) I appreciate it :)